# Two column UI for android app

Tags: android, user-interface

I am exploring different Android app UIs. I am trying to make one that has two columns, and on each column is a button that shifts into a different screen, but the two columns remain stationary.

An example to what I'm trying to replicate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BvLd.jpg

The 'list' and 'number' screens each have their own separate layouts, I think I need to do something with fragments, but I don't know where to start.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean two columns or two tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you dont know where to start you can go for `TabLayout` : [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) and `ViewPager` : [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and ofcourse `Fragment` :[Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) .You can create a layout like in the image by using this 3 items. Also you can follow this guide to create a screen like in the image, guide is so good for beginners : [google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout)

Additionally if you want to switch your `Fragment` when any of tab clicked, add this code :

```
tablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```